# Is it possible to make the Gear 2 smartwatch (running tizen) the bluetooth microphone for an android phone that it's paired with?

Tags: android, bluetooth, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

Basically I want to make the tizen smartwatch into a bluetooth headset for a period of time. We have a tizen and an android developer handy and we're willing to build **anything** necessary to make this work.

This kind of process seems to work with built-in android applications like the standard phone app. But there doesn't seem to be any documentation online as to how an app developer would leverage streaming the mic.

It should be noted that we do need to get the audio into the microphone input on the phone for our third party software to work. It's not as simple as just getting the audio to the phone.

Any help, even someone telling us what isn't possible, will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It is possible to play sound with the HTML audio tag: http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=269002&startId=zzzzz~&searchSubId=0000000032&searchType=ALL&searchText=sound
- It is possible to capture the sound in a Host Android application
- It is possible to exchange data bytes by bluetooth with the accessory SDK: http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile#accessory
  The data transfer is quick and efficient, so low quality sound may works with little delay

So it certainly is possible. But you'll have to code (or use compatible javascript and android libraries) all the streaming code which is quite a lot of work